# Is there an efficient way to solve De Mere's puzzle?

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

This question comes from Bertsekas' Introduction to probability, 2nd ed.

---

> A six-sided die is rolled three times independently. Which is more likely: a sum of 11 or a sum of 12?

I understand the solution 100%, but I am wondering if there is an efficient way to enumerate all the combinations; indeed the solution just lists them without going into how to obtain them.

I had to do it case by case, ie exhaust all possibilities of numbers in the 1st roll. e.g. Beginning with the first roll have a 1, I will enumerate all combinations of $1+x+y$ ($x$ being the 2nd roll and likewise for $y$) such that the total is 11...keep doing this all the way till the first roll is 6.

But this is a very inefficient way to do it, is there a better way of doing it?

[image]

Comment: Since here you are dealing with uniform r.v., you can exploit some properties of  the distribution of the sum, namely that it's symmetric around the mean, which is also the median. So, to establish whether $P(11)$ is greater than $P(12)$ you just have to check which value is closer to the mean.

Comment: @nicola Nitpick: I think you are using not only the fact that the distribution is symmetric but also that it's unimodal.

Comment: @bof Correct! You are right of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it, the question is not to calculate the probabilities, but simply to determine which is more likely, $11$ or $12$. Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ denote the result of the first, second, and third roll.

If $6\le X+Y\le10$, there is one way to make a total of $11$ with the third roll, and one way to make a total of $12$; even chances, as we are assuming a fair die.

If $X+Y\le4$ or $X+Y=12$, there is no way to make a total of $11$ or $12$.

If $X+Y=5$, there is one way to make $11$, no way to make $12$; if $X+Y=11$, there is  one way to make $12$, no way to make $11$. So the question boils down to: which is a more likely total with two dice rolls, $5$ or $11$? There are $4$ ways to make $5$ but only $2$ ways to make $11$ with two rolls, so $5$ is a more likely total than $11$ with two rolls, so $11$ is a more likely total than $12$ with three rolls.

Comment: Thank you that is indeed much more efficient; didn't even involve enumerating all the combinations

Comment: Very enlightening example how to calculate by omitting calculations.

Answer (score 3):

One way is generating functions. They are more sophisticated but not always efficient for a human to compute: You would imagine something like expanding
$$
(x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6)^3
$$
The coefficient of $x^k$ is the number of ways that $k$ can be obtained as the sum $a + b + c$ where $1 \leq a,b,c \leq 6$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(k,n)$ be the number of ways of getting a sum $k$ by throwing a dice $n$ times.

Then we have the recursion $$ A(k,n) = \sum_{j=1}^6 A(k-j,n-1) $$
with the initial conditions
$$A(k,0)= \begin{cases} 
 1 & \text{if } k=0\\
 0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

This at least gives you a simple way to compute any value. [Example in Python](https://www.ideone.com/ltS4Qk)

Or with pencil and paper ... or a spreadsheet:

[image]

---

Further: If you are familiar with probability, you can answer the question without computing the values. A single die has a uniform (discrete) [pmf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) with mean $(1+6)/2=7/2$. Then sum of thre dice, then, is the triple convolution of a uniform, which should be a bell shaped distribution, symmetric around the mean $3 \times 7/2 = 10.5$ - hence the maxima should be at $10$ and $11$. Hence we should have $p(11) > p(12)$